# How to call Azure pipeline template that included "resources"?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

For some reasons, I want my A.yml calling another B.yml from others repository.
Pipeline A is consider an 'empty' pipeline, its job is basically calling pipeline B, and B done the real job.
But B is not just steps, it contain all the details, it included 'Resources' also.

This is how I do:

Pipeline A:

```
trigger:
- main

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: script
    type: github
    name: xxx/script
    ref: refs/heads/main
    endpoint: smartracks

steps: **<---- What should I put ?**
 - template: B.yml@script
```

Pipeline B:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: rcu-service
    type: github
    name: abc/rcu-service
    ref: refs/heads/main
    endpoint: test
jobs:
    - job: OpenEmbedded_Build_And_Export
steps:
    - checkout: rcu-service
- script: |
    ......
```

If I excluded the "resources" in pipeline B, it will success (need add those resources into pipeline A).
But once I included resource in pipeline B, it fails with these message:

> ```
> B.yml@script(Line: 1, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'resource'
> B.yml@script(Line: 24, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'jobs'
> ```

In Pipeline A, this is how I call the pipeline B, I use **steps**, but it seems doesn't work.

```
  steps: **<---- What should I put ?**
     - template: B.yml@script
```

I try with stages, jobs, but fail too.

So, I am wonder what should I do ?
Please teach me, thank you.

Comment: Have you checked following replies? Are they helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Pipelines supports four kinds of templates:

- Stage
- Job
- Step
- Variable

It doesn't support `resources`, you need to put the `resources` in your A.yml.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#template-references

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you were to expand the template so that it showed up in the file where you placed `- template:...`. In this case, you would have

```yaml
steps:
 - jobs:
   ...
```

This doesn't work, because the schema requires steps to be a part of a job.

```yaml
jobs: 
  - template: B.yml@script
```

or

```yaml
stages:
- stage: stageName
  displayName: "my stage"
  jobs:
  - template: B.yml@script
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for sharing. Is there any way / workaround to make it work ?

Comment: You could try to structure your main pipeline file like one of the two samples I included in my answer?